# Using Stirling's formula to uniformly bound Bernoulli success probabilities (part 2)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

In [this paper](http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1970-07.pdf), the authors say that for any $\gamma \in [1/2,1)$, there is a positive constant $A=A(\gamma)$ such that for any $n$,

$$
\sum_{n\gamma\leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} \geq A n^{-1/2}2^{n \cdot h(\gamma)},
$$
where $h(x)=-x\log_{2} x - (1-x)\log_{2}(1-x)$.

They also say that that fact follows immediately from Stirling's formula. My question is **why does this follow from Stirling's formula?**

I'd prefer a push in the right direction to a full-fledged solution.

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047353/using-stirlings-formula-to-uniformly-bound-bernoulli-success-probabilities).

Comment: Keeping only the term $k=\gamma n$ in the LHS and applying Stirling already gives the RHS with $A(\gamma)=(2\pi\gamma(1-\gamma))^{-1/2}$, no?

Comment: @Did You're right, except that since $k= \lceil \gamma n \rceil$, I think it should be $A(\gamma) = (2\pi (\gamma + 1/2)(1-\gamma))^{-1/2}$, though the $1/2$ could be any $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @Did Actually there's another problem: since $k/n \geq \gamma$ (with $k=\lceil \gamma n \rceil$), $h(k/n)\leq h(\gamma)$, so $2^{n h(\gamma)} \geq 2^{n h(k/n)}$.

Comment: "Another" problem? The first remark was not a "problem". The second one neither, say, because $k/n\leqslant\gamma-1/n$ (and I am sure you can take it from here).

Comment: @Did I hate to let you down, but I'm still not getting it: $2^{h(k/n)} \geq 2^{h(\gamma + 1/n)}$ and so by continuity, for any $\epsilon$, $2^{h(\gamma+1/n)} > 2^{h(\gamma)}-\epsilon$ eventually. But that only means that $2^{nh(k/n)} \geq (2^{nh(\gamma)}-\epsilon)^{n}$, which doesn't seem to help. The problem I'm having is with that $n$ in the exponent.

Comment: Use $nh(\gamma+1/n)=n(h(\gamma)+h'(\gamma)/n+o(1/n))=nh(\gamma)+h'(\gamma)+o(1)$ hence $2^{nh(\gamma+1/n)}\sim2^{nh(\gamma)+h'(\gamma)}$ in the sense that LHS/RHS$\to1$.