# What is ${a \choose b+c}$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I wonder if there is a general formula for $\displaystyle{a \choose b+c}$ written by $\displaystyle{a \choose b}$ and some other constants, and why$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^N{n \choose pn+i}\leq \sum_{i=0}^N{n \choose pn}\left(\dfrac{1-p}{p}\right)^i?$$We assume $0<p<1$ and $n\geq (pn+i)\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: What's wrong with $a!/(b+c)!(a-b-c)!$?

Comment: If $p \in (0,1)$, is it always assumed that $pn \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Kaind yes, $pn\in \mathbb Z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $m=pn,$ so $p=\frac mn,$ this becomes:

$$\sum_{i=0}^N \binom{n}{m+i}\leq\binom nm\sum_{i=0}^N \left(\frac{n-m}{m}\right)^i$$

Now $$\binom{n}{m+i+1}=\binom{n}{m+i}\cdot\frac{n-m-i}{m+i+1}.$$ And $$\frac{n-m-i}{ m+i +1}\leq \frac{n-m}{m}.$$

So by induction: $$\binom{n}{m+i}\leq\binom nm\cdot \left(\frac{n-m}{m}\right)^i.$$

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047949/305862